# How to properly protect fence post with Flex Tape?

Tags: wood, fence

I was following the instructions in [this website](https://www.prowellwoodworks.com/index.php/post-holes/) to properly install a gate hinge post and I got confused on how to set up the flex tape. As part of the installation instructions, the author says:

> At the grade level, extending from approximately 1″ above the concrete, introduce the exterior weatherizing tape known as Vitchithane, or any number of names.

Later, the author also says:

> For this reason, taping the length of the post is precarious, only because if in fact you do not show care in insuring the tape is applied properly and providing a sure bond, then we are facilitating the bacteria and shortening the life of the post. The moisture that gathers between the post and the tape will have no where to go, festering in a perfect environment of no light and no air. So, although it is an acceptable allowance to tape the post for only one course of tape, at the concrete line, it is not advisable to tape the full post from the grade down. So, to repeat, do not tape the entire post from the grade down. Tape only that portion where the concrete cap extends to.

What I don't understand if it's suggested that the Flex Tape should go from 1' of the concrete all the way up to the top, or just take 4' or 8'. So, I'm not sure if I should do Picture 1 or Picture 2.

Picture 1
[image: Picture 1]
Picture 2
[image: Picture 2]

Moreover, I would like to know if it's a good idea to paint stain the 4x4 before putting it in the hole.

Comment: I've never seen anyone flex tape the wood to concrete interface.  The mentioned site even says without the tape the post will last 40+ years.  Flex tape hasn't even been around 40 years so hard to say if putting it on will actually make it last longer.  If you want longer than 40 years you should probably use concrete sono tube, steel U anchor and keep your post at or above grade.  My above grade gate post has been installed for 27 years and is likely fine for another 75.

Comment: Thanks, Fresh! It might be an old site :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the website is trying to tell you is to apply the tape to ONLY the portion of the post that will be underground and contacted by cement. They do advise starting the tape about 1 inch above the level of concrete.
Your 2 drawn pictures are backwards with the tape above the concrete. It should be 1 inch above and continue down protecting the post from contact with the concrete. The chemicals in concrete will degrade the wood if it is not treated.

Comment: RMDman. I am still confused because the author says: "At the grade level, extending from approximately 1″ above the concrete, introduce the exterior weatherizing tape known as Vitchithane". The author also says ":So, to repeat, do not tape the entire post from the grade down" What is the grade level and grade down?

Comment: Anything below the surface of the ground is "below grade"  What they are telling you is DO NOT apply the tape to the post all the way to the bottom of the post.  This is all assuming that you will have concrete only * inches or so in the post hole. beyond the concrete the post should be surrounded by pea gravel and that part of the post in the gravel below the concrete should NOT be covered by the tape. Refer to the pictures below.

Comment: It isn't chemicals in concrete that degrade the wood.  Concrete wicks and holds moisture.  Concrete directly against wood will keep that wood damp.

Answer (score 2):

The diagrams on that article show the concrete cap below the soil level, whereas your drawn diagrams do not.

[image: post setting diagram from the linked article]

Quoted explanation from the article, emphasis mine:

> The effectiveness of the tape is limited entirely to its seal against
> the post. **If used**, be sure that seal is complete, without any folds or
> areas where humidity, dew, rain, etc can enter that cavity between the
> tape and the post. To insure we have drainage in the event of a leaky
> sealed tape, **apply it only where the top concrete cap is**, plus 1/2″+/-
> above the (concrete) cap.

Note that the article is not recommending using a sealing tape, merely warning not to seal the entire underground portion of the post with the tape. If the tape ends 1/2" above the concrete cap, that would still be below the soil level in the diagrams given in the article.

I would say tape sealants are not a good idea, but I don't do post setting often so maybe someone with experience will disagree. I wrote this answer just to address some misunderstanding about the article as written.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frederic. Notice that I am referring to the For Gate Hinge Posts section in the article, where those diagrams don't seem to apply (since the concrete cap seems to go all the way to floor level), and it explicitly says to introduce the weatherproofing tape, right?

Comment: "So, although it is an acceptable allowance to tape the post for only one course of tape, at the concrete line, it is not advisable to tape the full post from the grade down. So, to repeat, do not tape the entire post from the grade down. Tape only that portion where the concrete cap extends to." - seems to indicate to tape just at the grade; the difference between this application and a regular post is that 1) the tape seems to be recommended, not just "allowed," and 2) it suggests using concrete all the way down, not pea gravel at the bottom of the post holes.

Comment: Thanks, Fredric. Actually it says to use the 3'' of gravel at the bottom. But what you says makes sense. Just out of curiosity, because I think that's what was confusing me... What is "the grade"?

Comment: Grade is the surface level.  The top surface of the soil.